# Distance among integer set

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, additive-combinatorics, integer-sequences

Given an integer set, if the distances between integers in the set are still in the set, what mathematical term should be used to describe that nature? Or what nature does the set have?

For example, $x,y \in \{1,2,3,4\}$, $m=|x-y|$, $m$ still $\in \{1,2,3,4\}$.
Is there a discontinuous integer set that has the nature?

Comment: You also have sets like $\{2,4,6\}$.

Comment: Is there any common characteristics to describe these sets? Or how to generate these sets?

Comment: Are your sets finite or infinite? Do they consist of *positive* integers only?

Comment: It's hard to figure out what the question is. Is it about metric spaces with integral distances? is it about subsets of the set of integers? and, last but not least, the question "if there is a discontinuous integet set that has the nature" is senseless.

Comment: For the example, $m = 0$ is not in the set. Can x equal y?

Answer (score 15):

To simplify notation define $\delta(x,y) = |x-y|$.
Here's an easier proof (using only Euclid)
of the result in the answer that **Seva** posted:
a finite set of positive integers closed under $\delta$
a homogeneous arithmetic progression $\{d, 2d, \ldots, nd\}$.

Let $d = \gcd(A)$.  By Euclid's algorithm, $\gcd(x,y)$ can be obtained from
$x,y$ by repeated application of $\delta$, so $A$ is closed under
pairwise $\gcd$; hence by induction $d \in A$.  Then $\max(A) = nd$
for some integer $n$, and $A \subseteq \{d, 2d, \ldots, nd\}$.
By repeated application of $\delta(\cdot,d)$
we find that $A$ also contains $(n-1)d$, $(n-2)d$, $(n-3)d$ etc.,
so $A \supseteq \{d, 2d, \ldots, nd\}$.
Therefore $A = \{d, 2d, \ldots, nd\}$, **QED**.

It soon follows that if $A$ is an infinite set of positive integers
and $A$ is closed under $\delta$ then
$A$ consists of all positive multiples of $\gcd(A)$.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming that your sets are finite and consist of *positive* integers only, every such set is a homogeneous arithmetic progression $\{d,2d,\dotsc,nd\}$, where $n=|A|$.

For the proof, let $A-A$ be the set of all differences $a_1-a_2$ with $a_1,a_2\in A$, and denote by $D_+$ the set of all positive elements of $A-A$. We have $D_+\subsetneq A$ (the inclusion is strict since the largest element of $A$ is not in $D_+$) and $|D_+|=(|A-A|-1)/2$. It follows that $|A-A|=2|D_+|+1\le 2|A|-1$, which is known to be possible if $A$ is an arithmetic progression only. It is then easy to see that the progression must be of the indicated form $\{d,2d,\dotsc,nd\}$.

Addressing a question in the comments.
To derive from $|A-A|=2|A|-1$ that $A$ is an arithmetic progression, one can use induction. Write $A=\{a_1,\dotsc,a_n\}$ with $a_1<\dotsb<a_n$, and let $A_0:=A\setminus\{a_n\}$. We have $(A_0-A_0)\cup\{a_n-a_1,a_1-a_n\}\subseteq A-A$, with the union in the left-hand side disjoint. Consequently, $|A_0-A_0|\le|A-A|-2\le 2|A_0|-1$, and by the induction hypothesis, $A_0$ is an arithmetic progression. Moreover, if $a_n$ were not the next term of this progression, then $(A-A)\setminus (A_0-A_0)$ would additionally contain the elements $\pm(a_n-a_2)$, leading to $|A-A|\ge|A_0-A_0|+4>2|A|-1$, a contradiction.

---

Here is yet another proof; as far as simplicity is concerned (see **Noam's** answer), this one is difficult to beat.

Suppose that $A=\{a_1,\dotsc,a_n\}$ has the property in question, where $a_1<\dotsb <a_n$. Since $a_2-a_1$ is an element of $A$ smaller than $a_2$, we must have $a_2-a_1=a_1$; that is, $a_2=2a_1$. Similarly, $a_3-a_1$ is an element of $A$ exceeding $a_2-a_1=a_1$, but smaller than $a_3$; hence, $a_3-a_1=a_2$, implying $a_3=3a_1$. Continuing this way, we get $a_k=ka_1$ for each $k=1,2,\dotsc,n$.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I want to know!

Comment: Sorry, I can not figure out the what note |  | means in your proof, and why the last equation means only arithmetic progression could be the answer?

Comment: @huicj: $|S|$ is the number of elements of the set $S$. I updated the answer to address your second question.

Comment: The second one is clear to comprehend. I know what "Moreover, if A0 is a progression (the induction hypotheses), while A is not, then (A−A)∖(A0−A0) additionally contains the elements ±(an−a2)." means, but I still confused about how to deduce A is an arithmetic progression. Maybe I think we should demonstrate $⊆$ in $(A0−A0)∪{an−a1,a1−an}⊆A−A$ is equivalent to $=$? Can you expand a little about this? Thanks again!

Comment: @huicj: I tried to explain that part of the (first) proof, hope is clear now.

Comment: How can we get $|A-A|-2 \leq 2|A_0|-1$?

Comment: @huicj: $A$ is assumed to satisfy $|A-A|\le2|A|-1$, and $|A|=|A_0|+1$. Thus, $|A-A|-2\le2|A|-3=2|A_0|-1$.